Failed to pair wireless mouse on 24.04
I have an Acer e5 573g with Ubuntu 24.04. When I try to connect the mouse (Logitech m240), I get the following error on a terminal running bluetoothctl
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCancelled.
I can get Ubuntu to show that the mouse is connected but it won't pair and won't work.
I can get other devices connected without problems.
The mouse works on a different PC with Windows 10/11.
Wireless adapter is Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377.
Anyone can help?

I once owned a couple of bluetooth mice back during the pandemic; never could get either to connect properly. I finally gave both of them to the local thrift store.
I have had much better luck with bluetooth earphones, headsets, and speakers; probably because the transmission is only one way once the adapter and the device have been paired.
Some advice, when you are trying to pair, make sure there are no other bluetooth transmitters around that may interfere with the two you are attempting to pair. You will also see visual progress if you use blueman-applet (graphical interface)
